# Connect to MySQL via SSH Tunnelling | MySQL Connection not available

Tags: python, mysql, ssh

I am using the following `python` snippet to connect my `MySQL` database on a shared hosting server.

```
import mysql.connector
import sshtunnel
with sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('server.web-hosting.com', 21098),
    ssh_username = 'ssh_username',
    ssh_password = 'ssh_pass!23',
    remote_bind_address = ('127.0.0.1', 3306)
) as tunnel:
connection = mysql.connector.MySQLConnection(
        user = 'db_user',
        password = 'db_pass',
        host = '127.0.0.1',
        port = tunnel.local_bind_port,
        database = 'demo',
    )
mycursor = connection.cursor()
query = "SELECT * FROM sample_table"
mycursor.execute(query)
```

I am getting the following error. I am able to connect to the database using `DBeaver` though.

```
MySQL Connection not available.
```

Comment: Please run ssh’d queries/statement with caution.  I’ve left jobs running overnight to come back and find they’ve timed out.  Recommend running directly on the database server (or local instance) if possible.

Comment: can you establish a ssh tunnel wioth another program, your code looks good if the tunnel is there

Comment: Yes, I could do it with DBeaver.

Comment: there is also the possiblity that local is already running a program on 3306, and so you have to add a local port too